# R10K puppetfile install without clearing custom modules

Tags: puppet

I made a few custom modules.

These custom modules are stored in my [R10K control-repo](https://github.com/puppetlabs/control-repo). So If I run `R10K deploy environment` the modules are in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/MY_BRANCH/modules/` and working.

I'm now wanting to use a few modules from Puppet Forge so I'm adding them to my `Puppetfile`, but when I run `r10k puppetfile install` the modules directory is completely cleared out and only the puppet forge modules are left.

What is the best solution to this?

---

Before:

```
-modules/
  -custom_facts/
  -custom_files/
```

After:

```
-modules/
  -certregen/
  -inifile/
```

Desired:

```
 -modules/
  -custom_facts/
  -custom_files/
  -certregen/
  -inifile/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a not very well-known option for a module install in a `Puppetfile`. It is the `local` option: https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k/blob/master/doc/puppetfile.mkd#local.

You can set it to `true` in your `Puppetfile` to avoid purging modules stored inside your control repo:

```
mod 'custom_facts', local: true
mod 'custom_files', local: true
```

After modifying the `Puppetfile` like above, use `r10k deploy display` to confirm the satisfactory results.

Note that another option is to move the local modules into another module directory. For example:

```
repo root dir
|── Puppetfile
|── local_modules
|   |── custom_facts
|   |── custom_files
```

R10k will ignore that directory during module deployments (but not during environment deployments of your control repo) and the modules will not be purged. However, you will need to setup your `enviroment.conf` to look for modules in that additional path: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/config_file_environment.html#modulepath